# How to copy a JPG file via Uri

Tags: android, file

Why is it not working? 
Edit: added new versions of code & logs:

```
    private void savePhotoFromCacheToFolder(Uri uri) {

    File goodPhoto = album.setUpPhotoFile(); //new empty JPG
    File currentPhoto = new File(uri.getPath()); //JPG from camera in cache

    Log.v(TAG, "\ngoodPhoto Path " + goodPhoto);
    Log.v(TAG, "\ncurrentPhoto Path " + currentPhoto);

    FileInputStream source = null;
    FileOutputStream destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentPhoto);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "\ncurrentPhoto not found ");
    }

    try {
        destination = new FileOutputStream(goodPhoto);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "\ngoodPhoto not found  ");
    }

    FileChannel sourceFileChannel = source.getChannel();
    FileChannel destinationFileChannel = destination.getChannel();

    long size = 0;
    try {
        size = sourceFileChannel.size();
        sourceFileChannel.transferTo(0, size, destinationFileChannel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "\nshit happens ");
    }

}
```

Logs:

```
V/MainActivity: goodPhoto Path /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Good photos/IMG_20170222_113700_-913025224.jpg
V/MainActivity: currentPhoto Path /cache/photo.jpg
V/MainActivity: currentPhoto not found 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.nio.channels.FileChannel java.io.FileInputStream.getChannel()' on a null object reference
```

It looks like Uri is not correct, but this Uri was returned by Camera app. Or maybe I have no access to cache folder, but earlier I did preview photo using this Uri.

Comment: Add some logging in catch and you will see what happened

Comment: Catching an exception and ignoring it is Very Bad.

Comment: @Selvin what we need to know?

Comment: Add a log in the `catch` and log the exception if any.

Comment: I don't know how legit this is, but this is works                                    `source = (FileInputStream) UriHelper.openInputStream(this, uri);`

Answer (score 0):

we have created an input stream and an output stream object. The input stream points to the current java file and the output stream is pointing to Output.java. It is to this Output.java we want the contents of the file to be transferred. As mentioned earlier, a file object is associated with a File Channel object. So, we obtain the File Channel object for both the input and the output stream using the following code,

```
public copyFile( String filePath ){


        FileInputStream source = new FileInputStream(filePath );
        FileOutputStream destination = new FileOutputStream("Output.java");

        FileChannel sourceFileChannel = source.getChannel();
        FileChannel destinationFileChannel = destination.getChannel();

        long size = sourceFileChannel.size();
        sourceFileChannel.transferTo(0, size, destinationFileChannel);
    }
```

Compare your code with above code , there is difference of method for transferring data and while is not used here.